# UIButton calls function from wrong class

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have a `ButtonProvider` class that creates my button and adds a target action. However, when the button is pressed, it doesn't call the function from the `ButtonProvider` class in which it was created, but instead calls a function with the same name from the other class.

```
class ButtonProvider {

    let view: UIView!
    let button: UIButton!

    init(view: UIView) {
        self.view = view
    }

    func showButton() {
        button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
        button.backgroundColor = .white
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ButtonProvider.close), for: .touchUpInside)

        view.addSubview(button)
    }

    @objc func close() {
        button.removeFromSuperview()
    }

}
```

And in my calling `ViewController`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    let buttonProvider = ButtonProvider(view: self.view)
    buttonProvider.showButton()
}

@objc func close() {
    //This is the function that is called
}
```

Any ideas why a selector of ButtonProvider.close calls my ViewController.close function?

Comment: Well, `buttonProvider` is not retained therefore it will get deallocated. I am amazed that the application does not crash.

Comment: Why you use #selector(ButtonProvider.close) instead of #selector(close) ?

Comment: @DmytroShvecov That's the same.

Comment: I am pretty sure that `close` cannot be called on the view controller, unless you explicitly add it as a target.

Comment: @Sulthan You're correct. I just created `buttonProvider` as an instance variable and it worked. Thanks so much. I had it in my head that it would be kept in memory for the lifetime of the application (which now that I think about it is rather silly). If you'd like to go ahead and add your comment as an answer, I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `buttonProvider` is not owned by the controller therefore it will be deallocated as soon as `viewDidLoad` ends. When the button is pressed the instance does not exist in memory any more and the result will be undefined behavior, usually a crash.

You will have to save `buttonProvider` to a strong property in the controller.

Comment: Thanks so much. Very helpful.